# C# JSON.NET convention that follows Ruby property naming conventions?

Tags: c#, ruby, api, json.net

I am using http://json.codeplex.com/ and I am talking to a Ruby based Rest API. Problem is that most of the properties have a ruby underscore naming convention. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way so that I can avoid having to Add lots of JsonProperty.

For example I want to avoid adding the JsonProperty attribute and have a convention built into the serializer settings so that it knows to try and map properties with an underscore in the to the .NET naming convention :)

```
public class Member
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "avatar_url")]
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "twitter_screen_name")]
    public string TwitterScreenName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "website_url")]
    public string WebSiteUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update - September 2016:**

Json.NET 9.0.1 has **[SnakeCaseNamingStrategy](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.htm)**. You can use that to have twitter_screen_name style properties automatically.

---

Inherit from `DefaultContractResolver` and override `ResolvePropertyName` to format property names as you'd like.

`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` does a similar global change to property names.

Comment: Thanks James will give it a shot and post my findings here for others who might run into this situation.

Comment: FYI, there is a potentially huge performance issue with contract resolvers with naming strategies in general. Massive decreases in throughput when using one (90TPS) vs. when not (600TPS).

Comment: Reuse the contract resolver. Creating a new one each time forces reflection to happen every serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 30):

Read this : http://nyqui.st/json-net-newtonsoft-json-lowercase-keys

```
public class UnderscoreMappingResolver : DefaultContractResolver 
    {
        protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
                propertyName, @"([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])|([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "$1$3_$2$4").ToLower(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for properties with two consecutive capital letters. `ThisIsATest` becomes `this_is_atest`.

Answer (score 14):

As of version 9, a new naming strategy property exists to do this, and it has a built-in [SnakeCaseNamingStrategy](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.htm) class. Use the code below and register `contractResolver` as `SerializerSettings.ContractResolver`.

```
var contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
contractResolver.NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy();
```

That class does not include dictionaries by default, and it does not override any manually-set property values. Those are the two parameters that can be passed in the overload:

```
// true parameter forces handling of dictionaries
// false prevents the serializer from changing anything manually set by an attribute
contractResolver.NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy(true, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

## This one worked for me

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new PascalCaseToUnderscoreContractResolver()
};
var rawJson = "{ test_property:'test' }"
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType>(rawJson, settings);
```

## Using Humanizer function "Underscore"

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer/1.37.7

http://humanizr.net/#underscore

```
public class PascalCaseToUnderscoreContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName) => propertyName.Underscore();
}
```

## MyObjectType class

```
public Class MyObjectType
{
    public string TestProperty {get;set;}
}
```