# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonString) returning all Properties<T> as Null

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

I am having trouble in converting a JSON string to a C# object. Very basic but not getting the desired output. What I am doing wrong?

Here is my string (as provided by Google authorization server)

```
 {
   "access_token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "token_type" : "Bearer",
   "expires_in" : 3600,
   "refresh_token" : "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
 }
```

Here is the class:

```
public class GoogleAuthProperty
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public long ExpiredIn { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing this:

```
var prop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleAuthProperty>(responseFromServer);
```

but not getting any values in the property list of `prop`

```
prop.AccessToken is null;
prop.ToeknType is null;
prop.ExpiredIn is 0;
prop.RefreshToken is null;
```

Reference:

```
Newtonsoft.Json
Version: 4.5.0.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# JSON.NET convention that follows Ruby property naming conventions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922874/c-sharp-json-net-convention-that-follows-ruby-property-naming-conventions)

Comment: I don't know how it should be able to map expire**s**_in to Expire**d**In :-)

Comment: try this below link which worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169825/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-returns-null

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The property names in your JSON do not match the property names in your class (because of the underscores), so you are getting default values.  You can fix this by decorating the properties in your class with the `JsonProperty` attribute and specifying the property name used in the JSON.

Use this class for deserialization

```
public class SampleResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```