# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> return null

Tags: .net, json

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return null, and I have no idea why ?

```
   public class FriendsData
   {
    public Friend friend { get; set; }
   }

   [JsonObject]
   public class Friend
   {
        [JsonProperty("count")]
        public string count { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<Items> items { get; set; }
   }

   public class Items
   {
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("online")]
    public int online { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hidden")]
    public string hidden { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("domain")]
    public string domain { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("online_app")]
    public string online_app { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("online_mobile")]
    public string online_miobile { get; set; }
   }
```

Here I load data from server

```
   var friend = vkUserInf.Load(friends);
   var jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FriendsData>(friend);
```

And after all i get null

Here is my JSON, that come in  variable friend

"{\"response\":{\"count\":109,\"items\":[{\"id\":105960511,\"first_name\":\"Anna\",\"last_name\":\"Vladimirovna\",\"domain\":\"pioneer_ann\",\"online\":1,\"online_app\":\"2274003\",\"online_mobile\":1,\"hidden\":1},{\"id\":209391889,\"first_name\":\"Bernard\",\"last_name\":\"Bouhidel\",\"domain\":\"id209391889\",\"online\":0,\"hidden\":1},{\"id\":220035155,\"first_name\":\"Damian\",\"last_name\":\"Wolkowski\",\"domain\":\"ijust_rock_and_no_more\",\"online\":1,\"online_app\":\"2274003\",\"online_mobile\":1}]}}"

If I change request string and  in JSON remain  only Array of Items, I can deserialize it easy, but with this field I have no idea

Comment: please post a valid json string so it could be tested

Comment: There are some non-printing characters preventing proper json parsing in what you have provided. Clean out the escape slashes and paste your json into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and you will see where the problems are.

Comment: Your JSON properties do not match your C# properties. Also, just searching on your title brings up several matches; did none of those help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsonconvert.deserializeobject returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169825/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-returns-null)

Comment: I have settled my problemm by addingproperty             public class            FriendsData{
       [JsonProperty("response")]
        public Friend friend { get; set; }
       }

Answer (score 0):

The main problemm was in this class

```
public class FriendsData
{
    //[JsonProperty("response")]
    public Friend friend { get; set; }
}
```

I have dropped out property,that I have commented