# Specify properties and field to encode and decode with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is it possible with Newtonsoft JSON to specify which fields should be encoded and which should be decoded?

I have an object, where all fields should be deserialized, but when serializing some fields should be ignored.

I know of `JsonIgnoreAttribute`, but that ignores in both directions.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632448/use-different-name-for-serializing-and-deserializing-with-json-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by relying on the [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) capability of Newtonsoft. All you need to do is to create a method named `ShouldSerializeXYZ` which should return a boolean. If the returned value is `true` then during the serialization the `XYZ` property will be serialized. Otherwise it will be omitted.

#### Sample Model class

```cs
public class CustomModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCreatedAt() => false;
}
```

#### Deserialization sample

```cs
var json = "{\"Id\":1,\"Description\":\"CustomModel\",\"CreatedAt\":\"2020-11-19T10:00:00Z\"}";
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomModel>(json);
Console.WriteLine(model.CreatedAt); //11/19/2020 10:00:00 AM
```

#### Serialization sample

```cs
var modifiedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
Console.WriteLine(modifiedJson); //{"Id":1,"Description":"CustomModel"}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!