# How to get JSON response same as the property name?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have my Response model class below.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Response
{
    [JsonPropertyName("PFUserID")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I am using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(jsonHelperResponse);` to get the deserialized response, and my jsonHelperResponse contains `PFUserID`.

But, because of this, my JSON response is,

```
{
  "PFUserID": "string"
}
```

I want it to return

```
{
  "UserId": "string"
}
```

Comment: A bit unclear. Do you mean that you want to deserialize with one property name, but serialize with a different name?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632448/use-different-name-for-serializing-and-deserializing-with-json-net

Comment: The easiest option - create another class with the same fields, map data to it and serialize it.

Comment: @Rotem Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: You will need to use a DTO or custom `JsonConverter<Response>` (or both if you define the DTO inside the converter).  In Json.NET you could use a custom contract resolver to override the name but System.Text.Json does not make its contract information public, see [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182) for confirmation.

Comment: @AndriiKhomiak - Querent is using System.Text.Json not Json.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `JsonConverter<T>` with System.Text.Json to do this:

Decorate your class with the converter:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResponseConverter))]
public class Response
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

(or if you don't want to pollute your class with attributes, add the converter to an instance of `JsonSerializerOptions`.)

Implement the converter:

```cs
public class ResponseConverter : JsonConverter<Response>
{
    public override Response? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException();

        var response = new Response();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                return response;

            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                throw new JsonException();

            string? propertyName = reader.GetString();
            reader.Read();
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "PFUserID":
                    response.UserId = reader.GetString();
                    break;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException("Ran out of JSON to read before the object ended.");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Response value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WriteString("UserId", value.UserId);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

So you can now read `PFUserID` from incoming JSON, and write `UserId` to outgoing JSON:

```cs
string jsonHelperResponse = @"{""PFUserID"": ""string""}";

Response deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Response>(jsonHelperResponse);

Debug.Assert("string" == deserialized.UserId);

string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(deserialized);
// {"UserId":"string"}
```