# how to set property name of a field for serialization only

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization

There is incoming response like this;

```
{
   "response_code":23
}
```

there is no issue reading data,

and I am able to read this value with this object;

```
public class APIResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("response_code")]
    public HttpStatusCode ResponseCode { get; set; }
}
```

But when I need to return this object to client as JSON it should look like this;

```
{
   "responseCode":23
}
```

so basically I want to change property name for serialization only, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Json.Net then you can use [conditional serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632448/use-different-name-for-serializing-and-deserializing-with-json-net) and a getter-only property.

```
public class APIResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("response_code")]
    public HttpStatusCode ResponseStatusCode { get; set; } //For deserialization
    
    public bool ShouldSerializeResponseStatusCode() => false;

    //[JsonProperty("ResponseCode")]
    public HttpStatusCode ResponseCode => ResponseStatusCode; //For serialization
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `[JsonProperty("response_code")]`
to `[JsonProperty("responseCode")]` of class `APIResponse`

May be two different classes for serialization and deserialization!

```
public class APIReadResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("response_code")]
        public HttpStatusCode ResponseCode { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class APIReturnResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("responseCode")]
        public HttpStatusCode ResponseCode { get; set; }
    }
```