# How to deserialize JSON (snake_case) to dynamic (PascalCase)?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-core, deserialization

This code works fine:

```
string json = @"{""MyProperty"" : ""bar""}";

var payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

string typedProperty = payload.MyProperty; //contains "bar"
```

Let's try to do the same with snake_case JSON. We add a `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` which is actually a [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922874/c-sharp-json-net-convention-that-follows-ruby-property-naming-conventions) to handle snake_case.

```
_snakeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new UnderscorePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

public class UnderscorePropertyNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public UnderscorePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy();
    }
}
```

Then, apply the settings to the `DeserializeObject` call. In case of deserialization to a static type, those settings are successfully applied to snake_case JSON:

```
string snakeJson = @"{""my_property"" : ""bar""}";

var payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(snakeJson, _snakeSettings);

string typedProperty = payload.MyProperty; //contains "bar"
```

OK, switch the target type to `dynamic`:

```
var payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(snakeJson, _snakeSettings);

string typedProperty = payload.MyProperty; //is null
string wrongProperty = payload.my_property; //is not null
```

As you see, `_snakeSettings` are ignored this time. I guess this is a bug. Does any workaround exist to do `JSON (snake_case) -> dynamic (PascalCase)` deserialization?

Environment:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` it acts the same way as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>`. `JObject` is not a real result of the deserialization, but some intermediate state of your data, It is closer to **readers** than to **objects**. E.g. it allows you to deserialize only part of a JSON
So seems like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` creates not a result object but a reach, functional reader for the JSON data. I suppose, that's why it shows you data as it was without any post processing

I suppose it's better to direct that question to a "Newtonsoft.Json" developers.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good example of unclear API. I'll report this issue, the reason why I started from SO is quite low activity in the official repo.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov this is not really the answer to your question. I need to do the same. Can you link to the issue you created in the official repo, please?